# Efficient way to work with JSON Webservices?

Tags: java, json, web-services

What are efficient ways to work with `RESTful JSON` webservices?

Best would be for me if I could work with `POJOs` that are auto-filled somehow after calling a webservice that responds with `JSON` data string.

The webservice does not provide any schema data like WSDL or XSD.
I know `Jackson` library can transform json strings into pojos. But therefore the pojos have to exist before.

So, how could I best auto-generate them, preferably using Jackson annotations.

Or otherwise, could you recommend different frameworks?

Comment: Without the web service provider "telling you" about the possible return values (such as in a WSDL in a SOAP service), there's no way you can just "generate" POJOs from nothing. Jackson comes with a generic `JSONObject` that, in some ways, acts like a `Map` (has values assigned to keys), which you can use for cases like this - but you aren't going to get domain objects unless you make them yourself, or unless the API provider has a client JAR that you can use.

Comment: how about [fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i can think of is to call the restful web service(jax-rs) and use the accept application/xml http header flag, this will return you an xml representation. Then use xjc and jaxb to create a schema and jaxb pojos from the xml, you can then use the same jaxb objects with the accept application/json http header and it should be auto converted into the jaxb java object from the json response. But then again you could have just created a pojo yourself and annotated it with jaxb annotations in the first place.